# .pptx files are not opening in firefox browser

Tags: browser

Opening a .pptx document fails in Firefox. Firefox tries to open the .pptx file as a .potx (MS PowerPoint template).

While opening the .pptx file , it prefixes with .potx extension. 
eg . **abcDocument.pptx.potx**

Does anybody knows the cause?

Answer (score 0):

You Must Open Tools-> Options -> Applications and find Power Point Presentation and edit action to save or open with another software .

Comment: So your problem is PowerPoint , maybe you should reinstall it or its extension

Comment: Hi , I reinstalled the Office powerpoint . But the problem is still there .

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be the issue of server MIME types.